# Loss of information in mariadb

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I am deploying mariadb with docker-compose and inserted a 270,000 row .csv file. Once I have it in the database I can work with it.

This file occupies 18 MB but when I restart the computer, the table still exists but its content does not. With other smaller tables I don't have this problem.

My docker compose is:

```
services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb
    restart: always

    volumes:
      - ./mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
     
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db_prueba'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'admin'
    ports:
      - 2022:3306
```

The error I get is:

> 2022-05-24 7:11:39 19 [ERROR] mariadbd: Cannot find record in 'df_munayapel_temp'.

How can I fix it?

My load code

```
# Defino el query con la sintaxis del insert 
query = inspect.cleandoc(f''' INSERT INTO DF_MunAyapel_Temp ( datetime,lat,lon,weather_main, weather_description ,variable,value) VALUES ( '{datetime}','{lat}','{lon}', '{weather_main}', '{weather_description}','{variable}','{value}') ''') 

# Ejecuto el query en MariaDB 
cur.execute(query) 
# Commit final para guardar las inserts, si hubo 
db_manager.commit() 
print('Commit') 
# Cierro la conexion a la DB 
print('Cerrando conexion a DB') 
cur.close() 
print('Fin ejecucion')
```

My Table is:

```
# conexion a MariaDb en docker.internal.host
db_manager = pymysql.connect(host='host.docker.internal', port=2022, user='root', passwd='admin', db='db_prueba')

print(db_manager)

cur = db_manager.cursor()
# Creación de la tabla
cur.execute("  CREATE TABLE `DF_MunAyapel_Temp` (   `datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `lat` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `lon` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `weather_main` VARCHAR(15) not null , `weather_description` VARCHAR(20) not null ,`variable` VARCHAR(15) not null , `value` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;")

records = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: But how do you load the `.csv` file to the database

Comment: I do it through a python script

Comment: Right, so are you sure that script is actually a) being run? b) running to completion? c) Doing a commit? ....... Maybe if you show it to us, we would be able to see any issues

Comment: In MySQL , we can use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement to do the import job : )

Comment: Could it be because of the size? With other files it doesn't happen, but with this one it does.

Comment: There is an [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72359495/edit) link under the question. You can click that any number of times to add information requested in a comment. Note how it is Very Difficult to read code in a comment, and the question is where people look for this sort of information, not a comment

Comment: is it a temporary table ? created like this : CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_name. or a memory table ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Comment: No, the table, you can see the creation of the table in my recently edited code. Thanks

Comment: I have just checked that it is a memory problem. When I insert less data, the data is persisted. How can I increase the memory of mariadb in docker?

Comment: Containers use up to the amount of memory on the host. How did you determine it to be a memory problem? Include details in your question.